# No puedo acceder a usuario en Terminal Centos 7 SSH

Tags: linux, centos

Puedo ingresar a la termina con el usuario ROOT pero al tratar de logearme con alguno de los usuario sucede que no tengo acceso.
Ejemplos-
1. Apago y enciendo la maquina. En el primer intento de acceso al tratar de ingresar con algunos de los usuarios que no sean ROOT, directamente no aparece ninguna advertencia o error pero no ingresa ( Directamente vuelve a pedirme que acceda a una cuenta ).
2. Cuando estoy logeado con ROOT e intento acceder a otra cuenta "su usuario1" me parece el siguiente error This Account is currently not available.

En el archivo etc/passwd/ tengo lo siguiente

> usuario1:x:1013:1013::/home/usuario1:/sbin/nologin

Intente modificarlo y quitarle el nologin agregando bash

> usuario1:x:1013:1013::/home/usuario1:/sbin/bash
>   pero tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que has puesto una shell que no existe.
Ejecuta lo siguiente en tu sistema para ver las shells de usuario disponibles:

```
# cat /etc/shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/sbin/nologin
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/nologin
/usr/bin/zsh
/bin/zsh
```

Como puedes ver, no existe /sbin/bash, sino /usr/bin/bash.
No se como has modificado la shell del usuario, espero que no fuera editando directamente el fichero /etc/passwd por si acaso te indico que la shell la cambies de la siguiente manera:

```
usermod -s /usr/bin/bash usuario
```

Comment: Exacto. Ese fue el error que tenia que cambiar. Ahora puedo ingresar a la terminal sim problemas. Muchas gracias!